# How do I use git_branch_create() on a repository hosted on Github?

Tags: c, github, libgit2

I am trying to figure out how to use this. I'm way out of my element here, so thanks for bearing with me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Libgit2 works primarily on repositories that you have disk access to, meaning you have to clone the repository before you can use libgit2 to work with it.

Once you've got that, you'll get a handle to your repository using [`git_repository_open`](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/repository/git_repository_open), and create the branch using [`git_branch_create`](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/branch/git_branch_create).